# Example of function which are closed function but may not be continuous

Tags: general-topology

I've found that function both open and closed but fail to be continuous. Now, I want to find an example of closed mapping that may not be continuous.

Comment: How about just $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x < 0 \\ 1 & x \ge 0 \end{cases}$

Comment: Superficially, the first sentence of your question seems to be enough to answer the second.  Could you clarify please?